# How should I access the vars which I set at theme_preprocess?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I am a beginner of drupal 7.
I create a new theme and write a preprocess function at template.php:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars){
  $vars[my_var]=array('var_0', 'var_1', 'var2');
}
```

How should I access $vars[my_var] at page.tpl.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the page template, e.g. `page.tpl.php` just type:

```
print $my_var['var_0'];
```

Hope this works... Muhammad.